# How to schedule three threads acting on a single object?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a requirement that,
3 threads are acting on a sinlge object, and that object has three methods, there is a method per each thread, like..

t1---> object.printOne(int number).
t2---> object.printTwo(int number).
t3---> object.printThree(int number).

now I want to make these threads synchronized and the object accessing should be in an order like

t1 prints....value
t2 prints....value
t3 prints....value
t1 prints....value
t2 prints....value
t3 prints....value
t1 prints....value
t2 prints....value
t3 prints....value
....and so on..

I have below code..
suggest me any techniqu

### One.java

```
public class One extends Thread {

    PrintNumbers p;
    int i = 1;

    public One(PrintNumbers p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int prev = 1;
        while (prev < 1111) {
            p.printOne(prev);
            prev = (int) (prev +  Math.pow(10, i));
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

### Two.java

```
public class Two extends Thread {

    int i = 1;

    PrintNumbers p;

    public Two(PrintNumbers p) {
        this.p = p;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int prev = 2;
        while (prev < 2222) {
            p.printTwo(prev);
            prev = (int) (prev + 2 * Math.pow(10, i));
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

### Three.java

```
public class Three extends Thread {

    PrintNumbers p;
    int i = 1;

    public Three(PrintNumbers p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int prev = 3;
        while (prev < 3333) {
            p.printThree(prev);
            prev = (int) (prev + 3 * Math.pow(10, i));
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

### PrintNumbers.java

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PrintNumbers {

    public enum status {
        A, B, C
    }

    status X = status.A;
    //
    public synchronized void printOne(int number) {
        //
        if (!X.equals(status.A) && !Y.equals(status.B)) {

            try {
                wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrintNumbers.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + number);
        X = status.B;

        notifyAll();

    }

    public synchronized void printTwo(int number) {
        //
        if (!X.equals(status.B) && !Y.equals(status.C)) {

            try {
                // System.out.println("under wait even");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrintNumbers.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + number);
        X = status.C;

        notifyAll();

    }

    public synchronized void printThree(int number) {
        //
         if (!X.equals(status.C) && !Y.equals(status.A)) {

            try {
                // System.out.println("under wait even");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrintNumbers.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + number);
        X = status.A;


        notifyAll();

    }
    //
}
```

### PrintTest.java

```
public class PrintTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintNumbers b = new PrintNumbers();

        One firstThread = new One(b);
        Two secondThread = new Two(b);
        Three thirdThread = new Three(b);

        secondThread.setName("second: ");
        thirdThread.setName("third: ");
        firstThread.setName("first: ");

        firstThread.start();
        secondThread.start();
        thirdThread.start();
    }
}
```

o/p:
first: 1
second: 2
third: 3
first: 11
second: 22
third: 33
first: 111
second: 222
third: 333
...and so on

Comment: Do you have any problem with the code? Could you please make it explicit? And what is `Y` in `PrintNumbers`? Did I miss something?

Comment: If you want the three threads be strictly serialized (means linearize their output) use one thread instead of three. If you insist on three threads, add a fifo queue per thread and let the threads put their output into their queues. Add a forth thread which takes output from queue 1, than queue 2 and so on.

Comment: @Michael this kind of 'serialize threads' question is now up there with 'FP compares don't work' and 'i = i++ + ++i;'.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` blocks in class `PrintNumbers` to `while` to obtain the desired behaviour

```
if (!X.equals(status.A) && !Y.equals(status.B))
```

to

```
while (!X.equals(status.A))
```

Also remove unused Y condition.